# Tkinter python dilemma

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

I am trying to write a python program using tkinter that will constantly check for new

emails. The problem I am having is that currently, the email gets updated only when the user

hits a button because I don't want my program to run before the user enter the correct

username and password.

How do I make sure that the program does not check for new emails if the user has not

entered the correct data but at the same time to constantly check for new emails once the

user has entered the data

Below is a part of my code:

```
    def printer(self):  
    self.mail=StringVar()
    self.username=self.userinput.get()
    self.MailPass=self.password.get()
    self.unread = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + self.username + ":" + self.MailPass +"@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])    #gmail command
    self.mail.set("Unread Emails:"+str(self.unread))
    self.mail_label=Label(self.frame,textvariable=self.mail)
    self.mail_label.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)


    return 

def showGUI(self):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    dhtreader.init()
    s = dhtreader.read(11,18)
    if s == None:
       s=(1,1)

    self.temp.set("Temperature:"+str(s[0])+" C")
    self.humidity.set("Humidity:"+str((s[1]))+"%")




    current_time = str(now.hour)+':'+str(now.minute)+':'+str(now.second)
    current_date=(str(now.month)+':'+str(now.day)+':'+str(now.year))
    self.time1.set("Time:"+current_time)
    self.date.set("Date:"+current_date)

    self.frame.after(100,self.showGUI)


def main():

root=Tk()
app=GUI(master=root)
app.showGUI()   
root.title('Controller GUI')
root.mainloop()



if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

printer is the method that is executed when the button is pushed. showGUI is where all the updating happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, so I'll answer all the possibilities I can think of.

Just call `self.frame.after(0, self.showGUI)` or `self.showGUI()` at the end of `printer`, after the user has entered the username and password. Then it will start checking every 100ms, and never stop, which is exactly what you want.

If you don't want it to require a button press, instead can you trigger `printer` to run any time focus leaves the username or password fields, or every time the contents of either changes, etc.; then you just have to check that the username and password are valid, and only call `showGUI` if they are.

If you want the username and password to be stored between runs of the program, you need to write code that does that. For example, you can store them in `printer`, and load them (if present) in the same class's `__init__`. I assume you already know how to read and write files; if not, see [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: calling self.frame.after(0, self.showGUI) or self.showGUI() at the end of printer freezes my program

Comment: @user3064033: That sounds like a different problem. If `showGUI` does anything slow or blocking (like that `dhtreader.read(11, 18)` maybe?), you can't do it in the main thread without freezing up the GUI. No matter how you solve your original problem, you will end up with that new problem. If that's your problem, see [Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) for how to deal with it.